# How can I convert C# Linq to Vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

How can I convert below code to vb.net?

I can not convert `select new { c.CustomerID, OrderCount = c.Orders.Count() };`

```
public void Linq76()
{
    List<Customer> customers = GetCustomerList();

    var orderCounts =
        from c in customers
        select new { c.CustomerID, OrderCount = c.Orders.Count() };

    ObjectDumper.Write(orderCounts);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's C#'s anonymous classes.  VB has support for that too. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx) example.

For basic info on using LINQ in VB:  try this [resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763068.aspx#Y1200).

Answer (score 4):

With [this tool](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/).

```
Public Sub Linq76()
    Dim customers As List(Of Customer) = GetCustomerList()

    Dim orderCounts = From c In customers New With { _
        c.CustomerID, _
        Key .OrderCount = c.Orders.Count() _
    }

    ObjectDumper.Write(orderCounts)
End Sub
```

[MSDN:Anonymous Types (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx)

Comment: This doesn't work. Tried converting `comboBox1.DropDownWidth = comboBox1.Items.Cast<string>().Max(x => TextRenderer.MeasureText(x, comboBox1.Font).Width);` - just kept processing - no result.